# How i can bind the transformation from a armature to a mesh

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature

Hi I'm trying to create 3 models for a game, everything is good until i realised that when i deleted the Armature from the model it make the meshes big, this is because in game it makes the model big enough for u to see it, now that im doing the mesh it it's small and i don't know how to do it big, but when i add the scale from the armature make it automaticly small
[image]

[image][image]

Also i have a doubt about the outliner and how the parentings i think work, what does the chopped lines indicate?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the parenting while keeping the transformations, select the mesh object(s), and run *Object > Parent > Clear and Keep Transformation*. You may need to apply the transforms afterwards by running *Object > Apply > All Transforms* or *Rotation & Scale* based on your needs.

The chopped line indicates which objects are children of the object at the top of the chopped line. In your case, *Armor*, *Backpack*, *BackwardsCap*, *Balaclava*, *Bandana*, *Beanie*, and *Beard* are children of *Armature*.

Comment: I want to do the reverse i want to do a big object into a tiny one, also thx –

Comment: You're welcome, but I don't quite understand what you mean. If you follow the steps I listed, your objects should have the same size after removing the parent. This way, you won't need to scale down big objects, because they won't become big to begin with.